# How do display vue data of clicked element from v-for in modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

This is how my json looks like. I display bunch of them in a v-for format and I am able to click on one of them. I would like to display the data from the element I clicked on in a modal.

```
[{
        "id": 1,
        "companyName": "test",
        "image": "https://mmelektronik.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Insert-logo.jpg.png",
        "location": "Warsaw",
        "salary": "10000",
        "skill": "Junior",
        "tags": "test",
        "jobDescription": "test",
        "title": "UI Designer"
    }

]    

Now I want to access only jobDescription and display it in the modal.
```

```
b-modal(hide-footer="", :id="id")
      template(#modal-title="")
        | Information
      .d-block.text-center
        p {{ want the jobDescription here }}
        b-button(variant="primary") Apply
```

This is how I open the modal.

```
  openModal(item) {
      this.offer = item;
      this.$bvModal.show(this.id);
    }
```

Component

```
  b-container
    b-card.joblist__post.mt-2(
      v-for="offer in filteredOffers",
      :id="id"
      :key="offer.id",
      @click="openModal"
    )
      .d-flex
        .joblist.d-flex.w-100
          .joblist__info.d-flex.align-items-center
            .company-logo.d-flex.align-items-center.mr-3
              b-img.logo(:src="offer.image")
            .joblist-name.d-flex.flex-column.text-left
              h5.mb-0.font-weight-bold {{ offer.title }}
              .located.d-flex.align-items-center.mt-2.justify-content-start
                b-icon.mr-2(icon="geo-alt-fill")
                p.m-0.text-secondary.joblist-span {{ offer.location }}
                b-icon.mx-2(icon="person-fill")
                p.m-0.text-secondary.joblist-span {{ offer.companyName }}
                b-icon.mx-2(icon="bar-chart-fill")
     

    b-modal(hide-footer="", :id="id")
      template(#modal-title="")
        | Information 
      .d-block.text-center
        p {{offer.jobDescription}}
      b-button(variant="primary") Ok


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      offers: (state) => state.offer.offers,
      loading: (state) => state.offer.loading
    }),
 
    filteredOffers(){
      return this.offers.filter((offer) => {
        return offer.title.match(this.search);
      })
      
    },

  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchOffers: "fetch",
    }),
    openModal(item) {
      this.offer = item;
      this.$bvModal.show(this.id);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchOffers();
    this.id = this._uid;
},
  
};
```

Comment: Can you please create a reproducible example?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You have v-for list as buttons. You click on a button, modal opens, and you want to display the information that the button contains from json in a modal.

Comment: Since you are setting `this.offer` in the parent, it should be usable.  Try `{{ offer.jobDescription }}`

Comment: @Dan , wont work this way, when I do this, the page goes blank

Comment: Well, that was a guess because it looks like you set `this.offer` in the parent.  But it's just a guess because you haven't shown the component.  You should show that.  Maybe it could be done straight from the `id` but it seems unnecessary and depends on what is defined in the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `data` to:

```js
data() {
  return {
    search: "",
    offer: null
  };
},
```

Use the following in your template:

```
p {{ offer.jobDescription }}
```

And change the `click` handler to:

```html
@click="openModal(offer)"
```

This suggestion from comments should work once `offer` is defined first in data and passed from the click.  You do set `offer` in the `openModal` action.

Your modal should not be inside `v-for`.  Take it out and hardcode an id:

```html
b-modal(hide-footer="", id="offerModal")
```

Open it:

```js
this.$bvModal.show('offerModal');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple approach you can take. Have a `selectedItem` attribute in data like so:

```
data: {
   return {
      selectedItem: {}
   }
}
```

and add an on click on the elements like so, where you assign the clicked object to selectedItem:

```
<button v-for="(e, i) in whateverDataArray" :key="i" @click="selectedItem=e">
    {{ e.companyName }}
</button>
```

Then simply pass the selectedItem as props to the modal and so when the modal appears, it'll show the props which was the clicked `selectedItem`!

**EDIT:** in your case you should remove the modal from the for loop as well. Also you don't need to pass in the `selectedItem` as props to the modal as you can access the `selectedItem`.